# Parse JSON String with many arrays and no identifer

Tags: c#, json.net

I am having problems parsing this JSON string.  I would like to loop through the balances.  I want to use a dynamic approach without creating a class for the result.  Hope somebody can help.

> [0,"ws",[["exchange","USD",0,0,null],["exchange","BTC",2.84658558,0,null],["exchange","BTG",0.00091586,0,null],["exchange","BCH",0,0,null],["exchange","IOT",0,0,null],["margin","BTC",0,0,null],["funding","BTC",0,0,null],["margin","USD",0.443,0,null],["exchange","DSH",0,0,null],["exchange","ETH",8.07766,0,null]]]

Comment: Um, `JArray.Parse(json)`? You say you have "problems" parsing it, but that's not much help when we don't know what you've tried. Please show us what you've tried and describe the problems you've run into.

Comment: Elaborate what you're having trouble with. We need specific errors, or a described problem you're having. Post the code you're running now that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague, but perhaps an example might help you.  The JSON consists of three levels of nested arrays.  The outermost array contains some miscellaneous data at the start (not sure what it represents) plus an array of rows at index 2.  Each row has an array of five columns, of which only the first three seem to be "interesting", based on your sample.  Here is how I would loop through the rows to display the "interesting" information using Json.Net's [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) class:

```
JArray root = JArray.Parse(json);
JArray rows = (JArray)root[2];
foreach (JArray row in rows)
{
    string desc = (string)row[0];
    string currency = (string)row[1];
    decimal amount = (decimal)row[2];
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-8} {1,-3} {2}", desc, currency, amount));
}
```

Output:

```
exchange USD 0
exchange BTC 2.84658558
exchange BTG 0.00091586
exchange BCH 0
exchange IOT 0
margin   BTC 0
funding  BTC 0
margin   USD 0.443
exchange DSH 0
exchange ETH 8.07766
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rmg2Jg